Multiple streamed response combined in a single iterator in Scala
I have multiple replicas of a service from which I am receiving a stream of response:
// RPC call to server that returns a stream of response.
def getResult(input: Request): Iterator[ResultItem]

On the client side I call this method in parallel on multiple threads:
val results: Seq[Future[Iterator[ResultItem]]] = requests.map{ request => 
  Future {
    getResult(request)
  }(ec)
}

I want to return a single stream of Iterator[ResultItem] that has the entries that have already been processed. How can I do this in scala? Essentially, how do I implement this method?
def getResults(inputs: Seq[Request]): Iterator[ResultItem] = {
  val results: Future[Iterator[ResultItem]] = inputs.map{ request => 
    Future {
      getResult(request)
    }(ec)
  }
  
  <SCALA MAGIC to COMBINE MULTIPLE STREAMS>
}

NOTE: The returned iterator should have entries available as soon as they are processed, irrespective of the the stream they are in. It shouldn't be that first all entries from Stream 1 are accessed and then Stream 2. If an entry in stream 2 is available before Stream 1, then that should be returned first.

TBH it looks like a task for reactive streams library like Akka (Pekko) Streams or FS2 - they have a build-in operators for merging side-effecting/async streams, while Iterable and Iterator OOTB support only operations over a closed world - the Iterator is mutable, and might produce new values but it is using a "complete" definition of the computation, without something trying to race several threads and blocking until the first result becomes available, to return it.

Meanwhile, Akka has https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/merge.html and FS2 has https://javadoc.io/doc/co.fs2/fs2-core_3/3.10.2/fs2/Stream.html#merge-fffff506.
